# Adding customized content on login page

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

Most of my ASP.NET website is accessible to an anonymous web users. However there are a few pages  that I require authentication before I allow access. I control this via the web.config:

```
<authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

Currently my logon.aspx file is generic, but I would really like to include instructions telling the user why he was redirected to the logon page. Something like:

> Before you can volunteer for a task, please logon so the system can identify you.

OR

> You've attempted to edit an event. The system only allows Administrators to do this. Please logon so we can verify you are an administrator of this event.

The instructions on the logon page would depend on what the user was attempting prior to the forms authentication redirect.

My problem is how can the logon page determine what action was taken? Is there anyway to pass a custom querystring to the logon page? I guess I could decode the ReturnUrl and use that to try an determine what instructions to display. However that approach just feels....dirty. I don't like the logon page having a dependency on the URL names of other pages in the system.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [HttpRequest.UrlReferrer Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.urlreferrer.aspx) to find out what was the user intention.

Or you could set a [QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring.aspx) / [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) variable before redirecting and use it to display some message.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use custom exceptions to do this.

```
public class ClassName: Exception
    {
        protected ClassName() : base() {}
        public ClassName(String message) : base(message) { }
    }
```

Then you do

```
public class First: ClassName
{
    public First() : base("message") {}
}

public class Second: ClassName
{
    public Second() : base("message") { }
}
```

Now you just catch exceptions of type ClassName and get the message value and pass it into an asp label or textbox or however you wish to do it

Comment: How would an exception propagate across an HTTP redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can also capture the redirect in global.asax's Application.EndRequest

```
void Application_EndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated && HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode == 302 && HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation != null && HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation.ToLower().Contains("login.aspx"))
        {
            // do some switching or determining here, or have items preset in your HttpContext.Current.Items[]
            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation += "&Action=blah";

        }
    }
```